# Systemd service keeps stopping

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

I have several systemd user services, but after a while they all stop (and restart), with little information. Here's one of the services, a Go web server:

```
[Unit]
Description=App

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/dev/app
ExecStart=sh /home/dev/app/run.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Enabled with `systemctl --user enable app` .

Looking in journalctl I see:

```
Jan 26 16:53:41 Ubuntu-2004-focal-amd64-base systemd[411708]: Started App.
Jan 26 17:03:44 Ubuntu-2004-focal-amd64-base systemd[411708]: Stopping App...
Jan 26 17:03:44 Ubuntu-2004-focal-amd64-base systemd[411708]: app: Killing process 411808 (renderer) with signal SIGKILL.
Jan 26 17:03:44 Ubuntu-2004-focal-amd64-base systemd[411708]: app.service: Succeeded.
Jan 26 17:03:44 Ubuntu-2004-focal-amd64-base systemd[411708]: Stopped App.
Jan 26 17:03:54 Ubuntu-2004-focal-amd64-base systemd[412783]: Started App.
```

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: What does run.sh contain?

Comment: just calls the golang binary with some parameters:
`./bin/app --env="dev" --logFormat="json"`

Comment: Do you remain logged in as that user / have you enabled linger?

Comment: no! tell me more about that

Comment: I've `sudo loginctl enable-linger my-user`; let's see if that works!

Comment: @TomYan this seems to have fixed it! dunno what's the MO here, but if you want to reply with that, I'll mark as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is explained in [logind.conf(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html):

> UserStopDelaySec=¶
>
> Specifies how long to keep the user record and per-user service user@.service around for a user after they logged out fully. If set to zero, the per-user service is terminated immediately when the last session of the user has ended. If this option is configured to non-zero rapid logout/login cycles are sped up, as the user's service manager is not constantly restarted. If set to "infinity" the per-user service for a user is never terminated again after first login, and continues to run until system shutdown. Defaults to 10s.

Although not explicity mentioned, enabling linger leads to a similar effect of "infinity" mentioned above (for the specfic user). Also, with linger enabled, the "user@.service" will be started on boot automatically even if when no login was attempted afterwards. (I am not aware that the latter is documented anywhere and I certainly hope that the devs won't ever change the behavior.)

The following setting is another one that is probably relevant. (I think processes here include the one running as a user service.)

> KillUserProcesses=¶
>
> Takes a boolean argument. Configures whether the processes of a user should be killed when the user logs out. If true, the scope unit corresponding to the session and all processes inside that scope will be terminated. If false, the scope is "abandoned", see systemd.scope(5), and processes are not killed. Defaults to "yes", but see the options KillOnlyUsers= and KillExcludeUsers= below.
>
> In addition to session processes, user process may run under the user manager unit user@.service. Depending on the linger settings, this may allow users to run processes independent of their login sessions. See the description of enable-linger in loginctl(1).

Note that login refers to those that with actual session spawned. `sudo -i` / `su -` does not count as far as I'm aware of.

Also, system service with `User=` specified is not the same thing as user service.

Comment: From what I remember, starting on boot was the original purpose of "linger" when logind was added. It's documented in loginctl(1).

Comment: Ah. I guess I mixed it up with [this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/22055) issue I bumped into. (It's probably an impression I got from Lennart's comment.)